# Trouble with subcaption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

[image: Group 1]

I generated the figure above by the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}, height=2in, width=2in]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [color=blue]coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot [color=red]coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\vskip 30pt

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}, height=2in, width=2in]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How should I modify my code to get figures like the following two?
[image: Group 2]
[image: Group 3]

Comment: Is there any better alternative to groupplot environment for this purpose?

Comment: Your problem are the missing captions? Add a \caption{} where you want it.